# How to Swing image like pendulum in android?

Tags: android, animation

I am beginner to Animation in Android.
I want to set animation like Pendulum(Swing left to right) to image in my Activity.

what I have done so far is:

```
Animation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 30, 0, 0);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
anim.setDuration(1500);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
```

But it doesn't work at all...
can anybody suggest me how to do Animation?

Thank You....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, and ended up with an xml-only solution: http://blog.sqisland.com/2012/01/android-pendulum-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

**This will help you ::**

```
      AnimationDrawable Tranninganimation5;

       Tranninganimation1 = new AnimationDrawable();
            new playninzi().execute();
            animation.setOneShot(false);
            Tranninganimation1.setOneShot(false);

private class playninzi extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                Signs_main_page.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
            this.dialog.show();

            try {
                for (int i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                            .decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                                    "http://203.a44.115.55/MRESC/images/test/girl2/"
                                            + "girl-1000" + i + ".png")
                                    .getContent());
                    Drawable frame = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                    animation.addFrame(frame, 50);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

in this example i have attach image from server but you can also set it drawable and display animation

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, and doing such complex animations, I would try looking into the simply API of [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to draw and animate objects. Take a look at [lunarLandar](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html) for an example.

Would be very simple, if you control the actual placement of the object, to simply create a formula that adjusts the X & Y of the object.

**Sudo:**

```
-If object is going right, and is left of center, decrease it's Y value.
-If object is going right, and is right of center, increase it's Y value.
-If the object is going left, and is right of center, decrease it's Y value.
-If the object is going left, and is left of center, increase it's Y value.
```